# Python Iterator Help + lxml

Tags: python, iterator, for-loop, lxml

I have this script-

```
import lxml
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from lxml.etree import fromstring
from lxml.html import parse



website = parse('http://example.com').getroot()


selector = website.cssselect('.name')


for i in range(0,18): 
    print selector[i].text_content()
```

As you can see the for loop stops after a number of times that I set beforehand. I want the for loop to stop only after it has printed everything.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering... Also just noticed I put the website as xxx.com.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to import `CSSSelect`, because you are using the `cssselect` method on the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSSSelector.cssselect() method returns an iterable, so you can just do:

```
for element in selector:
    print element.text_content()
```

Comment: If it's iterable, then why am I getting "TypeError: 'CSSSelector' object is not iterable" when I try to iterate it? edit: I forgot to do the "getroot" part

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
for e in selector:
    print e.text_content()
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I would expect you want a for loop like:

```
selectors = website.cssselect('.name , .name, .desc')

for selector in selectors: 
    print selector.text_content()
```